# Digit frequency program for large input

Tags: c, string, frequency

I have written the below program to find out number of times each digit is occurring in the array of characters.

```
int main(){

    char s[2000],count,j=0;
    fgets(s,2000,stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        count=0;j=0;
        while(*(s+j))
        {
            if(isdigit(*(s+j)))
            {
                if(i==(*(s+j)-'0'))
                    count++;
            }
            j++;    
        }
     printf("%d ",count);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it ain't working for large input.

```
b3n47b5xf13qlx233rg4u2c949i623e34nt5661se06b675utbpy258wz633855846l761d61x340h1vn19w191sj18v2u333556bh6m5uc4u050am05p961dhmpu6iq4667zg9
```

The expected output is

```
5 10 5 12 8 11 15 4 4 6
```

But the output I got is

```
5 10 5 12 7 11 13 3 4 5
```

Can anyone help me out in finding where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Why do you use the odd pointer notation `*(s+j)` instead of `s[j]`?

Comment: Upvoted for a proper [mcve].

Comment: Or simply a pointer (e.g. `char *p = s;` and loop (e.g. `while (*p)`, and comparison `if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')` you have your digit..., then increment `p`

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: @DYZ I used *(s+j) instead of s[j] because I had read ,using pointer notation instead of array,would make the program run faster and the code would also be more efficient.

Comment: This is not true and has not been true for the last 10 years or more.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to DYZ's answer, your logic is convoluted. You don't need to test both `if(isdigit(*(s+j)))` and `if(i==(*(s+j)-'0'))`, you simply need to refactor you code and provide a single test and use a frequency array.

(a simple array with 10 elements initialized to all zero where you increment the index that corresponds to each digit when that digit is found resulting in the count of that digit being present at the corresponding index when done)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 2048   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NDIGIT 10

int main (void) {

    char s[MAXC] = "";
    size_t digits[NDIGIT] = {0};    /* declare a 'frequency array' */

    while (fgets (s, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* read all blocks of data */
        char *p = s;                    /* pointer to s */
        while (*p) {                    /* for each char in s */
            if (isdigit (*p))           /* Am I a digit? */
                digits[*p - '0']++;     /* increment value at index */
            p++;                        /* increment pointer */
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NDIGIT; i++)
        printf (" %zu", digits[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Or without `ctype.h`,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 2048   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NDIGIT 10

int main (void) {

    char s[MAXC] = "";
    size_t digits[NDIGIT] = {0};    /* declare a 'frequency array' */

    while (fgets (s, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* read all blocks of data */
        char *p = s;                    /* pointer to s */
        while (*p) {                    /* for each char in s */
            if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') /* Am I a digit? */
                digits[*p - '0']++;     /* increment value at index */
            p++;                        /* increment pointer */
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NDIGIT; i++)
        printf (" %zu", digits[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

In both cases, the output with your input is:

```
 5 10 5 12 8 11 15 4 4 6
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is a really great code review. I see you've been on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) before. You should do more work like this over there!

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right. I just seem to run out of time after helping here. I'll make a point to keep another tab open in my browser.

Comment: Pedantic: 1) `isdigit (*p)` s/b `isdigit ((unsigned char) *p)` to avoid UB when `*p < 0`. 2) `size_t` is the best type for array sizing and indexing, yet that does not apply here to frequency counts.  As `stdin` may be re-directed from a file of TBytes in length, perhaps `unsigned long long` or simply `uintmax_t`.  Still an UV-able answer.

Comment: Ok, now I get the `size_t/uintmax_t` size issue. On smaller platforms, you may only get a `4-byte` (or less) `size_t` which doesn't protect against file sizes greater than the max for type. The cast to `unsigned char` for `isdigit` is advisable, but something I need to do to expand my normalcy beyond ASCII. Perhaps we can get the gcc folks to add a warning to `-pedantic` -- that would prompt me to remember each time.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `j` as `char` (and `count`, too, but it's a different issue). The largest value of a (signed) `char` variable is 127. When your string has more than 128 characters, `j` overflows: `j+1` becomes -128 rather than 128. Declare all variables that are used for indexing and counting as `int` or `size_t`.

Comment: If you think for a second, this architecture must have a signed `char`.  If char were unsigned and the string was 256 characters or longer, the program would never terminate.

Comment: I just fixed it before seeing your comment.

Comment: Just deleted my answer, since it said the same as yours now does. ;)

Comment: As size_t not int

Comment: "j overflows: j+1 becomes 0 rather than 128." is not likely occurring (maybe become -128) - yet correctly `j` overflowing is a problem.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you for explaining it so clearly.I changed the data type to int and now its working.