# Can we set a variable to a number range in C?

Tags: c, string, math

What I'm thinking of is something like this:

```
range = range <= '9' && range >= '0';
```

I want to extract a contiguous sequence of digits from a string. And once the program find a non-digit after it finds the sequence of digits, I want it to break out of the loop using `break;` in the second if-statement (line 59). And I think it would be much easier if I can just write the condition using a variable.

What I want to say in line 59 is "If the var `digit_flag` is TRUE and the element in the array s is included in the var `range`(which is a number range), then `break;`"

Can it be done?
If it can't, why not?

```
int i = 0;
int size_of_s = 0;
int digit_flag = FALSE;
while (s[i] != '\0') {
    if (s[i] == ' ') {
        i++;
    } else if (s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0') {
        size_of_s++;
        i++;
        digit_flag = TRUE;
    }

    if (digit_flag == TRUE && s[i] != range) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 59 is not available to your readers.

Comment: Yes, I've forgot to include it, just added it, thanks!

Comment: You may benefit from the discussion in [Digit frequency program for large input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681553/digit-frequency-program-for-large-input) asked/answered less than an hour ago. Same principles would apply, you would just need to add your `break`.

Comment: You could make a function to check for an ASCII digit. You could call the function `isdigit`, but unfortunately that name is already taken by a ctype.h function that checks for an ASCII digit. Hmm…

Comment: [don't put code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). It's useless and no one will click on that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to say in line 59 is "If the var digit_flag is TRUE and the element in the array s is included in the var range(which is a number range), then break;"
>   Can it be done?

As far as I know this can not be done in `C`.

> If it can't, why not?

Because there is no relational or comparison operator in the `C` language which means "operand 1 is within the range of operand 2" (even if the second operand is an array). You need to use a logical AND (&&) of two conditions (>= A, <= B).

If you don't want to use a standard function - such as `isdigit()`, which will use the range 0-9 - you could use a macro

```
#define IS_IN_RANGE(x, min, max) (x >= min && x <= max)
```

or *inline* function.

```
static inline int is_in_range(int x, int min, int max) {
    return (x >= min && x <= max);
}
```

Comment: the `isdigit()` function (or macro) is normally more efficiently implemented as it expands to a bitset verification over a precomputed array of character values.  something as `isdigit = flags[value] & FLAG_ISDIGIT;` requires only a bit and and an array dereference, against two comparisons and a boolean and operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "range" in C, you have to create one yourself:

```
// integer range class
// in this case it could also be a char range
struct int_range {
  int start;
  int end;
};

// range method to test for inclusinon
// in this case range could be passed as value efficiently, too,
// but passing as const pointer is more generic, so better example
bool int_range_contains(const struct int_range *range, int value) {
  return value >= range->start && value <= range->end;
}

// example usage
void func(void) {
  struct range digit_chars = { '0', '9' };
  int character = 'a';
  if (int_range_contains(&digit_chars, character)) {
    // something
  }
}
```

Of course this is a total overkill for this case. Your current `if (s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0')` is better, and every C programmer immediately sees what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
digit_flag == TRUE && s[i] != range
```

you can re-use what you already wrote

```
digit_flag == TRUE && !(s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the number sequence part in a string like

```
char str[]="hello1234isthesequence.";
```

you could just do

```
char seq[30];
if( sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%[0-9]", seq)==1 )
{
    printf("\nThe sequence is: %s", seq);
}
```

where the `%*[^0-9]` is used to read everything from `str[]` till a non-digit character is encountered and the `*` is to suppress it ie, it will be discarded and won't be assigned to anywhere.

Next the `%[0-9]` will read the remaining part of the string in `str` till and excluding non-number and assign it to `seq`.

`sscanf()` will return the number of total successful assignments that it made, which in this case should be `1`.

You may change the size of `seq` as per the size of the input string and change the width specifier in the format string of `scanf()` to avoid overflow.